# writing a function to replicate data

Tags: python-2.7

im writing a function that takes in two parameters data which is meant to be replicated and times which is the number of times data should be replicated.
im new to python,can anyone help out

```
def replicate_iter(times, data):
    output = times * data
    if type(data) != str:
        raise ValueError('Invalid')
    if times <= 0:
        return []
    else:
        return output.split(' ')

print replicate_iter(4, '5') #expected output [5, 5, 5, 5]

['5555']
```

Comment: Your `output` variable with the example input given does not contain a space character (which you use to split on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is commented and will give you the desired output, but utilizes a for loop of size `times`.

```
def replicate_iter(times, data):
    output = [] #you can initialize your list here
    if type(data) != str:
        raise ValueError('Invalid')
    #if times <= 0: # Since input was initialized earlier
    #    return [] # These two lines become unnecessary
    else:
        for i in range(times): #use a for loop to append to your list
            output.append(int(data)) #coerce data from string to int
        return output #return the list and control to environment

print replicate_iter(4, '5')
```

Output is:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `output.split(' ')`, but your input `'5'` contains no spaces.
Therefore `'5555'.split(' ')` returns `['5555']`. You will either need to change your return condition or add spaces between elements.

Adding spaces: (this assumes your string contains itself no spaces)

```
output = (times * (data + " ")).rstrip() # add a trailing space between elements and remove the last one
```

Changing the return / function: (this will support strings with spaces)

```
def replicate_iter(times, data):
    output = []
    if type(data) != str:
        raise ValueError('Invalid')
    while len(output) < times:
       output.append(data)
    return output
```